# Wordpress ?Login=failed

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

Ive created a custom login page in wordpress and added the code below to my template `functions.php` to prevent the custom login page from redirect to `wp-login` page when someone enters a wrong password or blank fields.
The problem is that if someone enters wrong credentials and then re-enters the correct info,  the custom login page still holds the `/?login=failed` string at the end of the URL.
For example it should be something like `www.something.com/customlogin/`
but it displays `www.something.com/customlogin/?login=failed` even though they logged in. Can you guys tell me if has to do with the code below. Thanks

```
add_action( 'wp_login_failed', 'custom_login_failed' );
function custom_login_failed( $username )
   {
    $referrer = wp_get_referer();

    if ( $referrer && ! strstr($referrer, 'wp-login') && ! strstr($referrer,'wp-admin') )
    {
        wp_redirect( add_query_arg('login', 'failed', $referrer) );
        exit;
    }
}



add_filter( 'authenticate', 'custom_authenticate_username_password', 30, 3);
function custom_authenticate_username_password( $user, $username, $password )
{
    if ( is_a($user, 'WP_User') ) { return $user; }

    if ( empty($username) || empty($password) )
    {
        $error = new WP_Error();
        $user  = new WP_Error('authentication_failed', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: Invalid username or incorrect password.'));

        return $error;
    }
}
```

### update

```
    <?php global $user_login;
    if(isset($_GET['login']) && $_GET['login'] == 'failed')
    {
        ?>
            <div class="aa_error">
                <p>Incorrect Password, Please Try again! If you have forgotten your password, please contact Sunday Capital and we will reset it manually. Thank You.</p>
            </div>
        <?php
    }
        if (is_user_logged_in()) {
            echo '<div class="aa_logout"> Welcome ', $user_login, '. <div class="aa_logout_user"><a id="wp-submit" href="', wp_logout_url( home_url() ), '" title="Logout">Click here to Log Out.</a></div></div>';
        } else {
             wp_login_form($args);

                  $args = array(
                            'echo'           => true,
                            'redirect'       => home_url('/account-access/'), 
                            'form_id'        => 'loginform',
                            'label_username' => __( 'Username' ),
                            'label_password' => __( 'Password' ),
                            'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me' ),
                            'label_log_in'   => __( 'Log In' ),
                            'id_username'    => 'user_login',
                            'id_password'    => 'user_pass',
                            'id_remember'    => 'rememberme',
                            'id_submit'      => 'wp-submit',
                            'remember'       => true,
                            'value_username' => NULL,
                            'value_remember' => true
                            ); 
        }

    ?> 

</section>
<!-- /section -->
```

Comment: change the form action to `/customlogin` in your template for the login box (html).

Comment: Why are you adding **?login=failed** in the first place? If you don't add it, it won't be there to be submitted.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the help.  Im not sure where to change it. My form looks like this. See next question.

Comment: @DonaldMichaels you can edit your question and insert your form code, into the original question, as your form code is not an answer it should not appear as an answer here.

Comment: my bad, didnt know that,   just updated it...

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for removing the /?login=failed string after a login. Perhaps someone can use it.

```
<?php global $user_login;
if(isset($_GET['login']) && $_GET['login'] == 'failed')
    {
        $new_url = esc_url( remove_query_arg( 'login' ) );
            $login = array(
                'remember' => false,    
                'redirect' => $new_url,                         
                'label_username' => '',
                'label_password' => '',
                'id_username'    => 'user_login_failed',
                'id_password'    => 'user_pass_failed'
            );


     } else { 

            $login = array(
                'remember' => false,                                
                'label_username' => '',
                'label_password' => ''
            );
    } ?>
<?php wp_login_form($login); ?>
```